# how to compare showdatepicker + showtimepicker results with current date (datetime.now())

Tags: flutter, datetime-format

I can get the date time values with date and time picker. I want to combine the date and time values ​​I have obtained and compare them with the current date (DateTime.now() format).
How can I do it?

```
Future _selectDayAndTime(BuildContext context) async {
 DateTime _selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: _date ?? DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: DateTime(2020),
    lastDate: DateTime(2100),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => child
);

TimeOfDay _selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: _time ?? TimeOfDay.now(),
);


if(_selectedDay != null && _selectedTime != null) {
  setState(() {
    _date = _selectedDay;
    _time = _selectedTime;
  });
  debugPrint("Day result : $_date");
  debugPrint("Time result : $_time");
 }
}
```

Result

```
I/flutter ( 9596): Day result : 2020-01-16 00:00:00.000
I/flutter ( 9596): Time result : TimeOfDay(18:30)
```

Answer (score 2):

TimeOfDay holds only hour and minutes. showDatePicker() returns a DateTime object, although it contains only year, month and day which are meaningful. You may update this DateTime object's hour and minutes with that of TimeofDay.

A vague code would as shown below.

```
var _date = _selectedDay;
var _time = _selectedTime;
var updatedDateTime = new DateTime(_date.year, _date.month, _date.day, _time.hour, _time.minute, _date.second);
```

And now, you can use standart DateTime class methods, to compare this updatedDateTime with DateTime.now().

Answer (score 1):

This might help you :

```
var date = DateTime.now();
var time = TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 00);

// Combined DateTime and TimeOfDay
var pickedTime = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, time.hour, time.minute);

// returns -1 if pickedTime is before, 1 if after, 0 if equal.
var comparison = pickedTime.compareTo(date);

// time between now and the time of day.
var duration = Duration(milliseconds: date.millisecondsSinceEpoch - pickedTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```